# How to handle read & write operations in different endpoint using Redis Client

Tags: redis, configuration, node-redis, redis-cluster, redisclient

Can we configure two different host for read and write operations in latest **redis client version 4.6.5**.

I was tried to configure the different redis server host read and write inside the createClient method but could't do that. Is there any other way to achieve this?
`redis.createClient()`

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  You can create two clients - 1 for each hostname

The closest thing would be https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/clustering.md